# What would be a good simple solution for data storage in a Silverlight application?

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml, silverlight

I have a silverlight application running on an IIS which currently has some data lists hard coded into the c#, not a good idea I know but this was for a proof of concept demo and now I need to move on to getting the data from another source which can be modified.

I've looked at xml files as well as an sql database.  The problem is that the client is reluctant to allow anything extra to be installed on the machine (long security process) and so sql express may not be practical.  I've also tried to look into sql compact edition but I cannot seem to be able to find any decent tutorials about it.

The data is made up of three, fairly short, lists of small objects which contain strings and integers.  I'm looking for a, preferably, simple and quick to implement solution which ideally does not need anything extra installing on the server.

Does anyone have any suggestions or links which may be handy?

Thanks in advance

Cap

Comment: It would help if characterised the data you need to "store".  Is it "static" data shared by all the clients (for example a Product catalog)?  OTH is it dynamically entered data owned only by each client?  Something else?

Comment: Ah good point.  It's static data in that there is a single data store used by all clients, much like a product catalog or something as you suggest.

Answer (score 1):

If you are comfortable using LINQ to query your data instead of SQL, [Sterling DB](http://sterling.codeplex.com/) sounds perfect for you.  It's extremely lightweight, and requires nothing extra on the server or the client (other than including it in your code obviously).  It uses isolated storage to store data.  All of the serialization/deserialization is taken care of for you by the library.

Edit:

Based on your comment that the data is "static" (meaning all clients consume the same data), it's probably best not to use a client-side database like Sterling or even (as you mentioned) SQL CE.  You are right to have reservations about hard-coding this type of "catalog" data, as changes in that data would require a new release of software.

A simple way to make the abstraction is to simply host an XML file alongside your XAP that contains all your data.  You can author the XML in any way you want.  In the software, it should be fairly straightforward to download the XML file, parse it, and populate your catalog each time the app runs.  When changes to the catalog are necessary, it's just a matter of modifying the XML file.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not an ideal solution but you could try using tab separated text files. They are the easiest to create.

Answer (score 0):

I use XML (web.config) to store data use by all clients such as pre-configure or default user setting value and use [Isolated Storage](http://www.silverlight.net/learn/graphics/file-and-local-data/isolated-storage-%28silverlight-quickstart%29) for client-independent data, such as, user UI-layout setting.

Answer (score 0):

I would serialize the objects to XML and store them on the server, it's relatively easy to do

You can pull the values into and XDocument

```
XDocument ConnectionStrings = XDocument.Load(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "ConnectionStrings.xml");
```

Here are the serialization function i'm using

```
    private static XDocument Serialize<T>(object obj)
    {
        XDocument ReturnValue = new XDocument();

        //Create our Serializer with the type that was passed in
        XmlSerializer Serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

        //Serialize our object to a string writer
        System.IO.StringWriter sw = new System.IO.StringWriter();        
        Serializer.Serialize(sw, obj);

        //We use a string reader to read the string from our Writer (created when serialized)
        System.IO.StringReader sr; 
        sr = new System.IO.StringReader(sw.ToString());

        //Then we can load the string reader giving us an XDocument
        ReturnValue = XDocument.Load(sr);

        return ReturnValue;
    }
    private static T Deserialize<T>(XDocument Xdoc)
    {
        T ReturnValue;

        //Create our Serializer with the type that was passed in
        XmlSerializer Serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

        //Create a string reader to access the XML data in our XDocument
        System.IO.StringReader sr = new System.IO.StringReader(Xdoc.ToString());

        //Deserialize the XML into our object
        ReturnValue = (T)Serializer.Deserialize(sr);

        return ReturnValue;
    }
```